# Simple math formula verification (normalize 0-100)

Tags: math, formula

How do I normalize any given number between 0 and 100?

The min is 0 and the max has no bounds (it's the search volume for a keyword).

`normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))` won't work since I have no definition of max.

Comment: You could use a non-linear mapping where `min -> 0` and `INF -> 100` - would that work for your application ?

Comment: @Henrik I like your formula. I made a test case with the following numbers:
129166 = 99.9(99)50713053562
3933 = 99.9(83)8133801513
6491 = 99.9(90)19226979924
440 = 99.9(55)31393721305
15525 = 99.9(95)89938955565
77766 = 99.9(99)1813648994

I basically trimmed the number and fetched the number that began at index position 4 and ended at index position 6. That gave me the most accurate result. But the thing I noticed is that all the higher numbers are close to 99, i can see why thought, I probably need to check index 5 through 7, but that is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @Paul R can you give me an example formula?

Comment: @Henrik's formula looks good, although you might want to correct for `min`, e.g. `200 / pi * atan(x - min)`.

Comment: @PaulR the minimum of the given number(x) is 0, will it affect the outcome?

Comment: OK - sorry - I missed that part of the question - in that case ignore my suggestion and just use @Henrik's formula "as is".

Comment: The comments and answer demonstrate that this question is off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Maths and belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Arcus tangens

Algebraically, you might start with some function that has poles, e.g. `tan`, and use its inverse,  `atan`. That inverse will never exceed a given limit, namely π/2 in this case. Then you can use a formula of the kind

```
f(x) = 100 * 2/π * atan(x - min)
```

If that doesn't produce “nice” results for small inputs, you might want to preprocess the inputs:

```
f(x) = 100 * 2/π * atan(a*(x - min))
```

for some suitably chosen `a`. Making `a` larger than one increases values, while for `0 < a < 1` you get smaller values. According to a comment, the latter is what you'd most likely want.

You could even add a power in there:

```
f(x) = 100 * 2/π * atan(a*(x - min)^b) = 100 * 2/π * atan(pow(a*(x - min), b))
```

for some positive parameter `b`. Having two parameters to tweak gives you more freedom in adjusting the function to your needs. But to decide on what would be good fits, you might have to decide up front as to what values you'd expect for various inputs. A bit like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20624086/1468366), although there the input range is not unbounded.

## Stereographic projection

If you prefer geometric approaches: you can imagine your input as the positive half of the *x* axis, namely the ray from (0,0) to (∞,0). Then imagine a circle with center (0,1) and radius 1 sitting on that line. If you connect the point (0,2) with any point on the ray, the connecting line will intersect the circle in one other point. That way you can map the ray onto the right half of the circle. Now take either the angle as seen from the center of the circle, or the *y* coordinate of the point on the circle, or any other finite value like this, normalize input and output properly, and you have a function matching your requirements. You can also work out a formula for this, and `atan` will likely play a role in that.

Comment: Thanks, I used this:
100 * 2/Math.PI * atan(Math.pow(0.0001*(kp.getSearch_volume()), 1))

And then I trimmed the outcome starting at 0 and ending at 5. This gave me what I was looking for, my thanks.

Comment: @user1275645: `Math.pow(x,1)==x` so that call is superfluous. So you basically say you trimmed to two digits after the decimal point, which I'd rather write as `Math.round(20000/Math.PI*atan(0.0001*kp.getSearch_volume()))/100`. That way you can be sure you won't encounter strange behaviour due to unexpected numbers of digits; you will always get the same number of decimals. Of yourse, you might also use `printf` or `NumberFormat` or something similar to print a value with a given number of decimals.